# Как разместить модуль из маркетплейс в папке local?

Tags: битрикс

Установили из маркетплейс модуль “Интеграция со СДЭК”. Ссылка на страницу модуля https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/ipol.sdek/#tab-rating-link 
Как можно грамотно перенести в папку local  модуль установленный из маркетплейс, чтобы затем сохранить в репозитории git, достаточно только скопировать папку самого модуля? Папки с модулями из маркетплейс также расположены  в bitrix/modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Необходимо удалить модуль из Битрикса с сохранением таблиц данных.
2. Переместить /bitrix/modules/ipol.sdek в /local/modules/ipol.sdek
3. Установить модуль заново.

Иначе можно получить проблемы с тем что будут попытки подключить файлы которых нет